# If $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ then $I(A)$ properly contains $I(B)?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So suppose $A, B$ are algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. If $B$ properly contains $A$ is it true that $I(A)$ properly contains $I(B)?$ I want to say no. If $B$ is a finite set then this is clear as we can construct a polynomial that only goes to 0 on the points in $B.$ However, is this true in general? Intuitively this seems true as we should be able to construct a polynomial that only goes to zero at a given set of points but I don't know how to show this or if this even true in general. What if $k$ is not algebraically closed?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an algebraic set, then $A=V(I(A))$ where $V(J)$ is
the set of common zeros of the functions in the ideal $A$. If
$A$ is a proper subset of $B$ then $A\subset B$ and so $I(A)\supseteq I(B)$. If $I(A)=I(B)$ then $A=V(I(A))=V(I(B))=B$, contradiction.

Comment: Note that the key word is "algebraic." I'm not sure the OP appreciates this point -- if A is not algebraic, its ideal can be the same as the ideal of a larger set.